# Show all types of missing values for a variable (sysmiss and extended missing values)

Tags: stata, missing-data

I have data containing three different types of missing values, the "usual" ones `.` and extended missing values `.a` and `.b`.

As I am working with numeric questionnaires, the sysmiss `.` are not interesting to me since they mean that the respondent just didn't reach this question (for a filtered question).
Extended missing values `.a .b` are "real" missing values (didn't answer/didn't know).

I would like to present a table showing the number of missing values for each kind, for example

```
Variable  |  (.)     |   .a     |   .b
__________________________________________________

Income    |   9      |   15     |    2
```

Any ideas on how to create such table? I looked at different commands in Stata, `tabmiss`, `missings`, `missing sum` without a clear answer for now.

Comment: MV may be standard locally or in your field for missing value, but not universally. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Of the commands you mention `missings` (_Stata Journal_) is mine and I can testify that the existing `tabulate, missing` was not functionality I felt I needed or wanted to re-create. Constructively, see @WIlliam Lisowski's helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that may point you in a useful direction.

```
clear
input x y z
1 1 1
. . .
3 .a .b
.b 4 .a
.a .a 5
end
list, clean
gen seqno = _n
rename (x y z) (vbl=)
reshape long vbl, i(seqno) j(variable) string
list, clean
rename vbl value
drop if !missing(value)
tab variable value, missing

           |              value
  variable |         .         .a         .b |     Total
-----------+---------------------------------+----------
         x |         1          1          1 |         3 
         y |         1          2          0 |         3 
         z |         1          1          1 |         3 
-----------+---------------------------------+----------
     Total |         3          4          2 |         9
```

Comment: `tab variable value if missing(value), missing` obviates the need for any `drop`.